# Empty API Response in Post method using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, post

I'm getting output as **ValueError API response is empty** . I've taken API code snippet from documentation only. What am I doing wrong here?
I tried quoting the payload data but it didn't worked.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
import json

url = "https://api.eflow.team/v1/affiliates/reporting/entity/table/export"
headers = {'X-Eflow-API-Key': 'myAPIkey','Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data = {
   "from": "2023-03-16",
    "to": "2023-03-17",
    "timezone_id": 80,
    "currency_id": "USD",
    "columns": [
        {
            "column": "offer"
        },
        {
            "column": "subid1"
        }
    ],
    "format": "csv"
}

data = json.dumps(data)

try:
    
    response = requests.post(url, data = data, headers = headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    if not response.content:
        raise ValueError("API Response is Empty")
    
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))
    
    if df.empty:
        raise ValueError("Empty CSV content")
    
    print(df.head)
    
except Exception as e:
    print(f" Error {e}")
```

Comment: could you try to print response status code after `request.post()`
`print(response.status_code)` do check you have response from the request

Comment: @SanuKhan yes, I tried that too. Its 200

Comment: are you seeing expected response when you log `print(f'response :{response.text}')`

Comment: no, its printing blank line

Comment: could you validate the request with a postman call